# Filtering an XML file using $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm querying a large (1000 nodes) XML file using the following code :

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        cache: false,
                        url: "someFile.xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        contentType: "text/xml",
                        success: function(xmlHttpRequest)
```

and the following XML structure :

```
<hospitals>
  <hospital>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>H1</name>
    <city>Riyadh</city>
    <tel>1234567</tel>
    <coordinates>27.034052,49.490662</coordinates>
  </hospital>
</hospitals>
```

My question is : Is there a way to filter (based on city for example) the XML file in place without reading the whole file and then filtering it by myself ? I'm pretty sure there is a field in the above call the does the filtering but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

use [parse XML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) like

```
var xml = "<hospitals>\
  <hospital>\
    <id>1</id>\
    <name>H1</name>\
    <city>Riyadh</city>\
    <tel>1234567</tel>\
    <coordinates>27.034052,49.490662</coordinates>\
  </hospital>\
</hospitals>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml.find( "city" ).text();

if($title=='Riyadh')
    alert($xml.find("tel").text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9JUNK/3/

or you can use [`dataFilter`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to filter the response and then process it in the success handler

```
dataFilter(data, type)Function
A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest.
This is a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response.
You should return the sanitized data. The function accepts two arguments:
The raw data returned from the server and the 'dataType' parameter.
```